# How to divide two array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays with the same dimension called

```
$array1 = ['10','20','30'];

$array2 = ['5','10','5'];
```

I want the result $array1/$array2

```
$result = ['2','2','6'];
```

Any idea??

Comment: Any atempts on your onwn? Did you try looping for example?

Comment: Using `array_map` `array_map(function ($a,$b) { return $a / $b; },$array1,$array2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use array_map, but in the background it's just looping the values anyways.
Because of that I genrally use a loop myself and I can controll what the output should be.

```
$array1 = ['10','20','30'];
$array2 = ['5','10','5'];

foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
    $result[$key] = $val/$array2[$key];
}

var_dump($result);
```

will give you the expected output.
But you could also do something like this in a loop:

```
$array1 = ['10','20','30'];
$array2 = ['5','10','5'];

foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
    $result[$val. "/" . $array2[$key]] = $val/$array2[$key];
}

var_dump($result);
```

which will give you:

```
array(3) {
      ["10/5"] => 2
      ["20/10"] => 2
      ["30/5"] => 6
}
```

Comment: you should add an empty $results array before the foreach.

Comment: @PaaPs there is no need for that in php

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
$array1 = ['10','20','30'];
$array2 = ['5','10','5'];
$result;

foreach ($array1  as $key=>$value) {      
   $result[$key] = $value/$array2[$key];       
}    

foreach ($result  as $key) {
  echo " $key";
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind for looping will mean you can't use associative arrays. In my opinion foreach is a better choice pretty much always